# Attribute Errors with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use SQLAlchemy to extract certain data. In this case, its for obtaining the age from a list of peopls stored in the "Profiles" class. However, when doing so, I get an error stating that: 'map' object has no attribute 'query'. I've tried doing this various other ways but it still results with an attribute error of sorts which makes me believe I'm not properly connecting or setting it up right?

```
profile_db = map(
  lambda uri: sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(uri), autoflush=True)(),
  [PROFILE_URI]
)

class pull_age(object):
  def on_get(self, req, res):
    person_age = profile_db.query(Profile).filter(Profile.id == req).first
    res.json = {'age of person': person_age}
```

Comment: Is this Python 3+?

Comment: yeah, Python 3.6.5 to be exact

Comment: In Python 3, `map` returns back a map object not a list. You'd need to wrap your map call with `list` to covert back to a list. Though now, you'd be calling the `query` method on a list?

Comment: Is there an alternate way you'd recommend that I could use to query the database of Profiles? When I wrap it in the list I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'`

Comment: Wrapping as in `list(map(lambda ... ))`. I'm not so familiar with sqlalchemy, but my suspicion is that you want to call the query method on each element of the `profile_db` list and not the list itself.

Answer (score 1):

The specific reason for the `AttributeError` is you're assigning a `map` object to `profile_db`, then trying to use it as a sqlalchemy `Session` instance. A `map` object is only meant to iterate through the results of applying a function to an iterable, so naturally doesn't have a `query` method, which leads to the exception. To get the resulting `Session` class you'd have to iterate through the `map` object. You're also not instantiating a session anywhere in the example code.

The larger issue is I'm not sure why you're using `map()` at all. You seem to be trying to call `sessionmaker` once, with a single `uri`, so why not just call it and pass the uri? The [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session) gives a basic example of using `sessionmaker`. Following that example, I believe you could do something like this:

```
# Create configured session class
Session = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(CLIENT_URI), autoflush=True)

# Create new session and do query
session = Session()
some_profile = session.query(Profile).filter(Profile.id == req).first()
```

Comment: This was a solution I had also tried earlier to amend this issue. The problem was, that in the line where you do: `Session = sessionmaker(bind=create_engine(CLIENT_URI), autoflush=True)`

I was getting an AttributeError: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_instantiate_plugins'`

Comment: Some digging [into the sqlalchemy source](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py#L50) shows that the `_instantiate_plugins` call occurs after attempting to parse the URL provided to `create_engine`. This suggests that there is a problem with your `CLIENT_URI`. Make sure that it's not `None`.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the correct way to be going about it but I'm currently putting it in as `CLIENT_URI = os.environ.get("CLIENT_URI")`